# How can I rename multiple files?

Tags: linux

I need a command to rename multiple files on my server. Currently I can use ssh to rename them

```
C++_Concurrency_in_Action.pdf_1.png
C++_Concurrency_in_Action.pdf_10.js
C++_Concurrency_in_Action.pdf_107.png
```

I need to replace ++ with _ and I am using this command
   `rename 's/\+/_/g' *`

there must be something wrong in my command.

Any help?

Comment: Can we have some information about your server? Are you running Linux? Windows Server? The only thing I can think of would be creating some sort of executable script that has a for loop and iterates all the files. Then you can ssh to it and just execute the script. Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not...

Comment: bspymaster; I have Linux server and I googled about this and found rename version can do this which uses perlexper. I have added the regex but this did not work. I suspect the problem is with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rana, use the escape characters and modify your rename command as follows:

```
rename 's/\\+/_/g' *
```

This shall replace all + with _ in all the file names.

Comment: I think one slash is enough for escaping the special characters in Regex ? like " rename 's/\+/_/g' * "